# Ubuntu KDE Partition Manage, how to use deleted windows partition unallocated memory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, dual-boot, hard-disk

EDIT: attached is the fdisk output! My system has about 300 gigs of unallocated space which you cant see in the terminal output.

[image: fdisk]

Using KDE Partition Manager on Ubuntu, I 'shredded' my windows partition which was taking up the majority of my hard drive which I really need now. Unfortunately, I am unable to move or resize any of these partitions according to KDE Partition manager.

can someone please help me move all that unallocated memory into my linux partition? I have read a couple tutorials but I don't know enough about the core concepts to actually try it on my particular system setup! [image: kde]

Thanks so much!

Comment: Consider adding the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` to your question.

Comment: It's better to use fdisk from command line.
Paste the output of sudo fdisk -l if are having doubt/trouble

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa thanks so much for the advice! I edited to show the fdisk output, please let me know if you can help me further!

Comment: @Jith Thank you! Just added a screenshot for clarity; let me know if you know how to help me!

Answer (score 0):

You have updated the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` and it is not showing free disk space.

Can you provide the output of `sudo fdisk -l`?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your only Linux partition is your root partition (mount point `/`). That cannot (practically) be unmounted while the operating system is running. You would need a bootable partition management tool, like [GParted Live media](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) to first *move* your partition towards the beginning of the disk (left in the graphical representation of the KDE Partition Manager). Since this basically requires relocating all the in-use data blocks of the partition that is being moved, the partition cannot generally be in use during the move - and since it's your root partition, you'll need a bootable media with the partition manipulation tool.

Since your disklabel type is GPT, and you don't have a BIOS boot partition, that indicates you are booting Linux with a native UEFI bootloader. That means there should not even be a need to reinstall the bootloader after moving the partition.

Once the free space is immediately to the "right" of the partition you wish to extend, extension will be possible.

Technically, the extension will happen in two steps: first, the partition table is rewritten to indicate the new size of the partition. Then, the filesystem metadata within the partition is updated to allow the filesystem to actually use the new size. In practice, tools like GParted and KDE Partition Manager may handle these two steps as a single operation if possible.